# How update Entity hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I wrote simple java project where you can create a schedule, but I have a problem with updating Course entity. im trying to write function which can add Lecture to Course : relation OneToMany. firstly I run .read function to get Lecture and then Course from the database, then by .getLectures().add() I want to add Lecture to Set which my Course class have and then by .update() function I try to update an information about course in database but nothing happens. hibernate make only select request. my code:

```
    Lecture lecture = lectureDao.read(lectureId);
    Course course = courseDao.read(courseId);
    course.getLecture().add(lecture);
    courseDao.update(course);

    @Override
    public Course read(int id) {
        transaction = currentSession().beginTransaction();
        Course course = currentSession().get(Course.class, id);
        currentSession().close();
        return course;
}

  @Override
public void update(Course course) {
    if (transaction == null) {
        try {
            transaction = currentSession().beginTransaction();
            currentSession().update(course);
            currentSession().flush();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentSession().close();
    }
}
```

_

```
public class Course {
@Id
private int courseID;
private String courseName;

@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Lecture> lecture = new HashSet<>();

public Course(){
    super();
}

public Course(String courseName, int courseID, Set<Student> students, Set<Lecture> lecture) {
    this();
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.students = students;
    this.courseID = courseID;
    this.lecture = lecture;
}

public int getCourseID() {
    return courseID;
}

public Set<Lecture> getLecture() {
    return lecture;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Course{" +
            "ID=" + courseID +
            ", courseName='" + courseName + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
public class Lecture {
@Id
private int ID;
private String lectureName;
private Date startTime;

public Lecture() {
    super();
}

public Lecture(String lectureName, Date startTime, int id) {
    this.lectureName = lectureName;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.ID = id;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public String getLectureName() {
    return lectureName;
}


public Date getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the entities.

Comment: @Lesiak edit: add entities code

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure, as we don't see entities code. Is that uni-directional or bi-directional mapping? Maybe you forget about @CASCADETYPE.PERSIST annotation?
Also I would recommend to make a method in Course.java for adding new Lecture to the Course, something like

```
public void addNewLecture (Lecture lecture) {
If (lectureList == null){
lectureList = new ArrayList<>();
} 
this.lectureList.add(lecture);
lecture.setCourse(this);
}
```

Sorry for bad formatting, but I'm on Android app right now

Comment: edit: add entities code